# Add class to child of li element on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hover, html-lists, addclass

**Problem:**
I would like to add a class to a child of an li element when it is hovered.

**HTML code:**

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="index.html" title="Homepage">Homepage<i class="icon-home"></i></a>
</li>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('li[ class="active" ]').hover(
            function(){ $(this).addClass('icon-white') },
            function(){ $(this).removeClass('icon-white') }
        )
    });
</script>
```

**Desired result:**

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="index.html" title="Homepage">Homepage<i class="icon-home icon-white"></i></a>
</li>
```

**Code for adding a class to a specific element:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {           
        if ($('#main-nav > li').hasClass('active') == true)
        {
            $("a > i", this).addClass('icon-white');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE (Final solution):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#main-nav li').hover(function() 
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active') != true)
            {
                $('a', this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-white');   
            }
        });

        $("#main-nav li.active > a > i").addClass('icon-white');
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active').hover(
    function() {
        $('a', this).addClass('icon-white');
    }, function() {
        $('a', this).removeClass('icon-white');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/qzKzd/1/)**

Also can write (Its better)

```
$('li.active').hover(
function() {
    $('a', this).toggleClass('icon-white');
});
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/96/)**

Using jQuery **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)** hover:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active').on('hover',
    function() {
        $('a', this).toggleClass('icon-white');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/qzKzd/1/)**

**According to comment**

#### How do I add class to `i`?

```
$('i', this).addClass('icon-white');
```

ans similarly for `.removeClass()` or `.toggleClass()`.

**According to edit**

```
$(document).ready(function(){          
     $("li.active > a > i").addClass('icon-white');
});
```

**[DEMO 4](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/3f3kr/2/)**

**Combining with hover:**

```
$("li.active > a > i").addClass('icon-white');

$('li.active').hover(
function() {
    $('a', this).toggleClass('icon-white');
});
```

**[DEMO 5](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/3f3kr/5/)**

Comment: How would I do if I want to add the class "icon-white" to an <i> element if the <li> parent has class="active"?

Comment: I have updated the code to illustrate my intention. In other words, on document load the jQuery should find an <li class="active"> and add "icon-white" to class for it's child <i> element.

Comment: Now comes the final problem. When the page loads a "icon-white" should be added to "li.active > a > i". This works perfectly now. However, when combined with .toggleClass it will remove the "icon-white" on hover. I want the "icon-white" to remain for the active element.

Comment: @kexxcream that means on hover `icon-white` will switch to `a` and on hover out it switch to `i`, right?

Comment: "icon-white" should only be applied to the <i> element within the <a> element. I apologize if I didn't make this clear in my description. On page load "icon-white" should be applied to li.active > a > i and on hover for the li.active it should remain. For <li> that does not have the class "active" it should be applied accordingly.

Comment: @kexxcream do you see the domo 5? if then write what you want within that demo as comment and share the link

Comment: Thanks to you @thecodeparadox I am becoming self-going :) I have updated the code with the correct solution.

Comment: $thecodeparadox Absolutely, it was the <i> element I wanted to add the 'icon-white' to, not the <a> element.

Comment: @kexxcream I think my solution do that job

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li.active').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('a').toggleClass('icon-white') 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like ->

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('li.active').hover(
      function(){ 
        $(this).children("a").addClass("icon-white"); //Add an active class to the anchor
      },
      function() {
        $(this).children("a").removeClass("icon-white"); //Remove an active class to the anchor
      }
   )
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going in right way... you just have to remove "function(){ $(this).removeClass('icon-white') }"  and put it in mouseout event ..like-

`$(".active").hover(function () {
            $(".active a").addClass('icon-white');
        });`
        `$(".active").mouseout(function () {
            $(".active a").removeClass('icon-white');
        });`

If you have any doubt, feel free to ask :)
Happy coding !!!!